# gRPC client not working when called from within gRPC service

Tags: java, grpc, distributed-system

*Quick disclaimer*, I am very new to gRPC and RPC in general, so please have patience

I have two gRPC servers running on the same java application, `Service A` and `Service B`.
`Service A` creates **multiple clients** of `Service B` which then synchronously makes calls to the various instances of `Service B`

**The server**

`Service A` has a rpc call defined by the `.proto` file as

```proto
rpc notifyPeers(NotifyPeersRequest) returns (NotifyPeersResponse);
```

the server side implementation,

```java
@Override
public void notifyPeers(NotifyPeersRequest request, StreamObserver<NotifyPeersResponse> responseObserver) {
    logger.debug("gRPC 'notifyPeers' request received");
    String host = request.getHost();
    
   
    for (PeerClient c : clients.values()) {   
        c.addPeer(host);    // <----  this call
    }

    NotifyPeersResponse response = NotifyPeersResponse.newBuilder()
            .setResult(result)
            .build();

    responseObserver.onNext(response);
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
}
```

The list of peers, `clients` are built up in previous rpc calls.

```java
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(peer).usePlaintext().build();
ClientB client = new ClientB(channel);
clients.put(peer, client);
```

**The client**

```proto
rpc addPeer(AddPeerRequest) returns (AddPeerResponse);rpc addPeer(AddPeerRequest) returns (AddPeerResponse);
```

the server side implementation,

```java
@Override
public void addPeer(AddPeerRequest addPeerRequest, StreamObserver<AddPeerResponse> responseObserver)  {
    logger.info("gRPC 'addPeer' request received");
    boolean result = peer.addPeer(host);
    AddPeerResponse response = AddPeerResponse.newBuilder()
                .setResponse(result)
                .build();
    responseObserver.onNext(response);
    responseObserver.onCompleted();
```

the client side implementation,

```java
public boolean addPeer(String host) {
    AddPeerRequest request = AddPeerRequest.newBuilder().setHost(host).build();
    logger.info("Sending 'addPeer' request");
    AddPeerResponse response = blockingStub.addPeer(request);
    return response.getResponse();
}
```

When I run this application, and an RPC is made to `Service A` and the client connection is created that calls  `addPeer`, an ambiguous exception is thrown, `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN` which then causes the JVM to shut down. I have no idea how to fix this, or whether it is even possible to create an gRPC client connection within a gRPC server

for all of my gRPC server implementations I'm using **blocking** stubs.

`<grpc.version>1.16.1</grpc.version>`
`<java.version>1.8</java.version>`

I've pretty much hit a brick wall, so any information will be appreciated

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **UNKNOWN** message is an exception on the server side that was not passed to the client.
You probably need to increase the log level on the server to try to find the root cause.

In this post [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2624) ,
creating the channel like below, enable it to see a more meaningful error message:

```
ManagedChannel channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress( host, port )
                .protocolNegotiator(ProtocolNegotiators.serverPlaintext() )
```

Answer (score 0):

If A and B are in the same application have you considered making direct function calls or at least using the [InProcessChannelBuilder](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/inprocess/InProcessChannelBuilder.java) and [InProcessServerBuilder](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/inprocess/InProcessServerBuilder.java)?

As mentioned elsewhere, in the current setup you can try increasing the log level on the server side (in B) to see the source of the exception.